# Invalid Authsub token in Google sites for apps

Tags: java, google-sites, authsub

I do not get any error while trying to access feed content for google sites from application hosted on gmail authenticated account. But I get

```
Token invalid - Invalid AuthSub token.
```

when I try to access application from google apps accounts managed GAE application.

I have tried both https://sites.google.com/feeds/ and http://sites.google.com/feeds/

I have also noticed that when Authsub prompts for grants access the address is taken as domain name address of site something like extra.mydomain.com whereas when page is loaded it is redirected to Google sites address https://sites.google.com/a/mydomain.com/pagename

The windows client is able to access the feed of same site whereas the web app is not getting through.

Stack trace

> at com.google.gdata.client.http.HttpGDataRequest.handleErrorResponse(HttpGDataRequest.java:564)
>       at com.google.gdata.client.http.GoogleGDataRequest.handleErrorResponse(GoogleGDataRequest.java:543)
>       at com.google.gdata.client.http.HttpGDataRequest.checkResponse(HttpGDataRequest.java:536)
>       at com.google.gdata.client.http.HttpGDataRequest.execute(HttpGDataRequest.java:515)
>       at com.google.gdata.client.http.GoogleGDataRequest.execute(GoogleGDataRequest.java:515)
>       at com.google.gdata.client.Service.getFeed(Service.java:1053)
>       at com.google.gdata.client.Service.getFeed(Service.java:916)
>       at com.google.gdata.client.GoogleService.getFeed(GoogleService.java:631)
>       at com.google.gdata.client.Service.getFeed(Service.java:935)
>       at morefile.UploadApp.getFileCabinets(UploadApp.java:92)
>       at morefile.CopyOfUploadApp.doPost(CopyOfUploadApp.java:196)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:713)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:806)
>       at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:487)

Answer (score 0):

I am just guessing here, but I believe the authentication service views your windows client app and web app as separate applications and require each to have a different auth token? How did you obtain the token? from the windows client? Can you try and obtain a token again from the web based client?

Comment: @aldrin The two are independent behavior. I illustrated them to point out that it works in one but not in other. I am not reusing tokens etc.,